# Selenium : How to handle a window which automatically closes and back to parent window & Opens window PopUp

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, firefoxdriver

I have a test case with following scenario:

1. Click on global Order Mgmt Super user
2. Click on Sales Order link
3. Which Actually Opens new Window & Closes automatically
4. Focus came back to Parent window & Open up a window popup
5. Click on Ok button

**Code :**

```
// Click on Global Order MGMT Superuser role & Sales Order

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Global Order Management Super User')]")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"N104\"]")).click();


        Set <String> handles =driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator<String> it = handles.iterator();

        String parent = it.next();
        String child = it.next();

        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();


        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
```

**Error :**

```
FAILED: testCase1
org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: 
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:05:20.749Z'
System info: host: 'ADONGAR-LAP', ip: '10.180.179.18', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 64.0, capabilities: {desiredCapabilities: {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox}}, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 23748, moz:profile: C:\Users\adongar\AppData\Lo..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 7e3fd1a5-32e0-4fb5-b83c-5f46f14ee28a
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createEx
```

Comment: On new open window do you perform any action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this help you:-

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Global Order Management Super User')]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"N104\"]")).click();
    // It will return the parent window name as a String
     String mainWindow=driver.getWindowHandle();
     // It returns no. of windows opened by WebDriver and will return Set of Strings
     Set<String> set =driver.getWindowHandles();
     // Using Iterator to iterate with in windows
     Iterator<String> itr= set.iterator();
     while(itr.hasNext()){
     String childWindow=itr.next();
     // Compare whether the main windows is not equal to child window. If not equal, we will close.
     if(!mainWindow.equals(childWindow)){
     driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);
     // If you just want to print or match the title of new opened window.
     System.out.println(driver.switchTo().window(childWindow).getTitle());
     }
     }
     // This is to switch to the main window
     driver.switchTo().window(mainWindow);
     // Wait for 10 seconds to find the Alert on parent window.
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

I have just write this on the basis of your test steps.

Answer (score 0):

Since it does not seem that you perform any actions on newly opened window and as you say it closes automatically I would just focus on the alert, as this is where the exception occurs.

remove this part:

```
Set <String> handles =driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> it = handles.iterator();

String parent = it.next();
String child = it.next();

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

and add a `FluentWait`:

```
FluentWait<WebDriver> fluentWait = new FluentWait<>(webDriver)
        .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(500))
        .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .ignoring(NoAlertPresentException.class);
fluentWait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()).accept();
```

Bare in mind that the alert that can be addressed this way is a default browser alert. If the popup you mention is something specific to your app it has to be handled like any other WebElement (`FluentWait` can still be used to wait for it, but the code would be different).